# How to generate a Fustion Chart Widget with time stamps

Tags: xml, fusioncharts

I am using Fusion Charts '[Real-Time Stacked Area Chart / Widget](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Contents/DataStreaming/XMLRealTimeStackedArea.html)'.

In my case I want to create 1 hour of historical data before the real-time data kicks in.

From the '[documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Contents/DataStreaming/XMLRealTimeStackedArea.html)' it explains I have to plot all the data for each dataset, see the [set tag](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Contents/DataStreaming/XMLRealTimeStackedArea.html#Anchor22). My problem with this is that not every datapoint for a particular dataset will have data.

Using the '[categories](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Contents/DataStreaming/XMLRealTimeStackedArea.html#Anchor18)' and '[category](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Contents/DataStreaming/XMLRealTimeStackedArea.html#Anchor19)' tags it only allows the data points to be set as labels rather than actual values to plot against.

Is there a way to plot my datasets against physical points, ie. make categories actual time / date values rather than just labels?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by `Is there a way to plot my datasets against physical points, ie. make categories actual time / date values rather than just labels?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the historical data can be provided to the real-time charts as static data only, as per FusionWidgets XT XML/JSON data format.

So, if you need the 1 hour history data to be plotted before fetching the current data, you could dynamically generate the XML string by fetching the history data on first time loading the chart in the browser.

Also, by generating the data dynamically, the category labels and their corresponding values (set elements) would be aperiodic, which will satisfy your needs.

Please note that FusionCharts framework does not support time Stamp and date/time axis for the X-axis to plot. You would need to provide the date/time as string labels in the category element.

Hope this clarifies!